# Angular APP_INITIALIZER is not delaying the app initialization when returning a promise

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use the APP_INITIALIZER in my root/app module to resolve the authenticated user from the API (PHP/Laravel).  I don't want to store the user object in localStorage, so I just store the JWT token, and go get the user on page refresh.  However, a feature module (lazy loaded) is loading before the promise returns from the service I created to run with the APP_INITIALIZER.

```
//app.module.ts
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';

import { StartupService } from './startup.service';
...
export function initConfiguration(startupService: StartupService) {
  return () => startupService.load();
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
     StartupService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initConfiguration,
      multi: true,
      deps: [StartupService]
    },
  ],
...


//The startup.service.ts
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'app/core/auth.service';
@Injectable()
export class StartupService {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  load(): Promise<boolean> {
    let auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
    if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      auth.getLoggedInUser().subscribe(
        response => {
          //everything from here on is happening after app init
          return Promise.resolve(true);
        },
        error => {
          return Promise.reject(false);
        }
      );
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works and resolves, just not when I expect (I thought the APP_INITIALIZER resolves before any feature modules are loaded???

Comment: This example may work - https://dormoshe.io/articles/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is that you can't return anything from the `subscribe` function.

You can try something like this:

```
import { AuthService } from 'app/core/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class StartupService {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  load(): Promise<boolean> {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {        
       if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
          auth.getLoggedInUser().subscribe(response => resolve(true), 
                                           error => reject(false));
       } else {
         resolve(true);
       }
    });

    return promise;

  }
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you.  I was also able to get it to return by converting it with .toPromise().then() instead of subscribe.

Comment: Yes. I tried the above with few modification. Instead of promise outside innner level observable, Directly called Observable call (subscribe). Then it's working has expected. thanks

Comment: remove load(): Promise<boolean> { call the load() without promise (reject, resolve)